# How to edit gridview without loosing rowdatabound changes?

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview

I have a table as below in vb.net  to display accounts created with grid view control.

[image]

As you can see I used `RowDataBound` to change header colors and hide edit and delete.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If (TryCast(GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("hflvl"), HiddenField).Value = 2) Then
                Me.GridView1.Rows(i).BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightBlue

                Me.GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text = ""
                Me.GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text = ""
            Else
                Me.GridView1.Rows(i).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        'lblMsg.Text = ex.Message & ex.StackTrace
    End Try
End Sub
```

Everything is working fine, below is the edit code

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowEditing
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    PopTransDataGrid()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(sender As Object, e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCancelingEdit
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    PopTransDataGrid()
End Sub
```

But when I click edit in a row all the rows under the edit row gets default style, And rowdatabound code Is Not effecting.
Even the delete, And edit Is showing for the Main accounts.

[image]

Here is my gridview code,

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomerDeplst" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="AccountNo" Width="99%" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC"
    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" ShowFooter="True" PageSize="50" Font-Names="Verdana"
    Font-Size="11px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#f2f2f0" />
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AccountName" SortExpression="AccountName">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountName" runat="server" Height="19px" Text='<%# Bind("AccountName")%>' Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AccountName")%>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hflvl" Value='<%# Bind("lvl")%>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" ReadOnly="True">
             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to delete?')" Text="Delete"
                 CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' CommandName="Delete" />
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
             <ItemStyle ForeColor="#0066FF" Width="100px" />
        </asp:CommandField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="lvl" HeaderText="Lvl" ReadOnly="True">
             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
             <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#006699" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
</asp:GridView>
```

How to edit gridview without loosing the style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the conditional style applied, the condition is a `HiddenField` in the `RowDataBound` event is present with a value of 2, however, in the ASPX page the `HiddenField` is only present in the `ItemTemplate` and not in the `EditItemTemplate`, so when the data is bound inside the `EditItemTemplate` the event applies the styles in the `Else` condition since it can't find the `HiddenField`.

EDIT: to clarify - the `HiddenField` must be in the `EditItemTemplate` for the event to apply style correctly, e.g. based on your ASPX:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountName" runat="server" Height="19px" Text='<%# Bind("AccountName")%>' Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hflvl" Value='<%# Bind("lvl")%>' runat="server" />
</EditItemTemplate>
```